# How to reset cumsum after change in sign of values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
In [46]: d = np.random.randn(10, 1) * 2

In [47]: df = pd.DataFrame(d.astype(int), columns=['data'])
```

I am trying to create a cumsum column where it should reset after a sign change in data column, like this

```
   data  custom_cumsum
0    -2  -2
1    -1  -3 
2     1   1
3    -3  -3
4    -1  -4
5     2   2 
6     0   2 
7     3   5 
8    -1  -1 
9    -2  -3
```

I am able to achieve this with `df.iterrows()`. I am trying to avoid iterrows and do it with vector operations. There are couple of questions on [resetting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29421356/2698552) [cumsum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18196811/2698552) when there is NaN. I am not able to achieve this cumsum with those solutions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create new key to `groupby`, then do `cumsum` within each group

New key Create: By using the sign change , if change we add one then it will belong to nest group

```
df.groupby(df.data.lt(0).astype(int).diff().ne(0).cumsum()).data.cumsum()
Out[798]: 
0   -2
1   -3
2    1
3   -3
4   -4
5    2
6    2
7    5
8   -1
9   -3
Name: data, dtype: int64
```

Comment: That magic `diff().ne(0).cumsum()` sequence is genius!  Worth memorizing.  It'd be amazing if there's a book out there that teaches you functional snippets like that for data manipulation.