# A groupby cumsum that is set to zero and restarts the cumsum when the value is below zero

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to create a column with cumulative sum that resets to zero when the cumsum gets below zero. I the following data:

| id | treatment | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | drugs | 66 |
| 1 | drugs | 33 |
| 1 | drugs | -100 |
| 1 | drugs | 11 |
| 1 | drugs | 30 |
| 1 | drugs | -50 |

The desired result:

| id | treatment | days | cumsum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | drugs | 66 | 66 |
| 1 | drugs | 33 | 99 |
| 1 | drugs | -100 | 0 |
| 1 | drugs | 11 | 11 |
| 1 | drugs | 30 | 41 |
| 1 | drugs | -50 | 0 |

Is there a solution close to this attempt?

```
df.groupby(['id','treatment']).days.apply(lambda x: 0 if x.cumsum() < 0 else x.cumsum())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend use this `numba` function this time:

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def cumli(x, lim):
    total = 0
    result = []
    for i, y in enumerate(x):
        total += y
        if total < lim:
            total = 0
        result.append(total)
    return result

df['cumsum'] = df.groupby(['id','treatment']).days.transform(lambda x: cumli(x.values,0))
```

Comment: But is this vectorized? If it's not, are you not worried about the speed?

Comment: numba is typically much faster than any pandas methods.

Comment: @user17242583 you can test the speed on your side ~ :-)

Comment: @HenryEcker yes it is ~ :-)

Comment: Exactly what I was after, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Building off of [@BENY's excellent answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49390415/17242583), you can do this:

```
df['cumsum'] = df.groupby(df['value'].lt(0).astype(int).diff().ne(0).cumsum())['value'].cumsum().clip(lower=0)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   id treatment  value  cumsum
0   1     drugs     66      66
1   1     drugs     33      99
2   1     drugs   -100       0
3   1     drugs     11      11
4   1     drugs     30      41
5   1     drugs    -50       0
```

Comment: I don't know if it matters but the OP attempt is `df.groupby(['id','treatment'])...` it seems that the cumsums could be distinct per `id` and `treatment` (which works for this sample since there is only 1 `id` `treatment` pair.) but may not work on the full dataset

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice. You're probably right (although the groupby has no effect on the _sample_ data :)

Comment: @HenryEcker is right, but thanks for the suggestion!