# pandas series add with previous row on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to add a series with previous rows only if a condition matches in current cell. Here's the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
        data = {'col1': [1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 0]}
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1'])
        df['continuous'] = df.col1
        print(df)
```

I need to `+1` a cell with previous sum if it's `value > 0` else `-1`. So, result I'm expecting is;

```
   col1  continuous
0      1           1//+1 as its non-zero
1      2           2//+1 as its non-zero
2      1           3//+1 as its non-zero
3      0           2//-1 as its zero
4      0           1
5      0           0
6      0           0// not to go less than 0
7      3           1
8      2           2
9      2           3
10     0           2
11     0           1
```

Case 2 : where I want instead of  `>0` , I need `<-0.1`

```
data = {'col1': [-0.097112634,-0.092674324,-0.089176841,-0.087302284,-0.087351866,-0.089226185,-0.092242213,-0.096446987,-0.101620036,-0.105940337,-0.109484752,-0.113515648,-0.117848816,-0.121133266,-0.123824577,-0.126030136,-0.126630895,-0.126015218,-0.124235003,-0.122715224,-0.121746573,-0.120794916,-0.120291174,-0.120323152,-0.12053229,-0.121491186,-0.122625851,-0.123819704,-0.125751858,-0.127676591,-0.129339428,-0.132342431,-0.137119556,-0.142040092,-0.14837848,-0.15439201,-0.159282645,-0.161271982,-0.162377701,-0.162838307,-0.163204393,-0.164095634,-0.165496071,-0.167224488,-0.167057078,-0.165706164,-0.163301617,-0.161423938,-0.158669389,-0.156508912,-0.15508329,-0.15365104,-0.151958972,-0.150317528,-0.149234892,-0.148259354,-0.14737422,-0.145958527,-0.144633388,-0.143120273,-0.14145652,-0.139930163,-0.138774126,-0.136710524,-0.134692221,-0.132534879,-0.129921444,-0.127974949,-0.128294058,-0.129241763,-0.132263506,-0.137828981,-0.145549768,-0.154244588,-0.163125109,-0.171814857,-0.179911465,-0.186223859,-0.190653162,-0.194761064,-0.197988536,-0.200500606,-0.20260121,-0.204797089,-0.208281065,-0.211846904,-0.215312626,-0.218696339,-0.221489975,-0.221375209,-0.220996031,-0.218558429,-0.215936558,-0.213933531,-0.21242896,-0.209682125,-0.208196607,-0.206243585,-0.202190476,-0.19913106,-0.19703291,-0.194244664,-0.189609518,-0.186600526,-0.18160171,-0.175875689,-0.170767095,-0.167453329,-0.163516985,-0.161168703,-0.158197984,-0.156378046,-0.154794499,-0.153236804,-0.15187487,-0.151623385,-0.150628282,-0.149039072,-0.14826268,-0.147535739,-0.145557646,-0.142223729,-0.139343068,-0.135355686,-0.13047743,-0.125999173,-0.12218752,-0.117021996,-0.111542982,-0.106409901,-0.101904095,-0.097910825,-0.094683375,-0.092079967,-0.088953862,-0.086268097,-0.082907394,-0.080723466,-0.078117426,-0.075431993,-0.072079536,-0.068962411,-0.064831759,-0.061257701,-0.05830671,-0.053889968,-0.048972414,-0.044763431,-0.042162829,-0.039328369,-0.038968862,-0.040450835,-0.041974942,-0.042161609,-0.04280523,-0.042702428,-0.042593856,-0.043166561,-0.043691795,-0.044093492,-0.043965231,-0.04263305,-0.040836102,-0.039605133,-0.037204273,-0.034368645,-0.032293737,-0.029037983,-0.025509509,-0.022704668,-0.021346266,-0.019881524,-0.018675734,-0.017509566,-0.017148129,-0.016671088,-0.016015011,-0.016241862,-0.016416445,-0.016548878,-0.016475455,-0.016405742,-0.015567737,-0.014190101,-0.012373151,-0.010370329,-0.008131459,-0.006729419,-0.005667607,-0.004883919,-0.004841328,-0.005403019,-0.005343759,-0.005377974,-0.00548823,-0.004889709,-0.003884973,-0.003149113,-0.002975268,-0.00283163,-0.00322658,-0.003546589,-0.004233582,-0.004448617,-0.004706967,-0.007400356,-0.010104064,-0.01230257,-0.014430498,-0.016499501,-0.015348355,-0.013974229,-0.012845464,-0.012688459,-0.012552231,-0.013719074,-0.014404172,-0.014611632,-0.013401283,-0.011807386,-0.007417753,-0.003321279,0.000363954,0.004908491,0.010151584,0.013223831,0.016746553,0.02106351,0.024571507,0.027588073,0.031313637,0.034419301,0.037016545,0.038172954,0.038237253,0.038094387,0.037783779,0.036482515,0.036080763,0.035476154,0.034107081,0.03237083,0.030934259,0.029317076,0.028236195,0.027850758,0.024612491,0.01964433,0.015153308,0.009684456,0.003336172]}
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1'])
        lim = float(-0.1)
        s = df['col1'].lt(lim)
        out = s.where(s, -1).cumsum()
        df['sol'] = out - out.where((out < 0) & (~s)).ffill().fillna(0)
        print(df)
```

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421356/pandas-cumulative-sum-on-column-with-condition) answers your question?

Comment: @erentknn looks promising, checking..

Comment: Why are two last rows `0`? Should they be `2,1`?

Comment: @QuangHoang corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `cumsum` function on booleans:

Give me a +1 whenever `col1` is not zero:

```
(df.col1 != 0 ).cumsum()
```

Give me a -1 whenever `col1` is zero:

```
- (df.col1 == 0 ).cumsum()
```

Then just add them together!

```
df['continuous'] = (df.col1 != 0 ).cumsum() - (df.col1 == 0 ).cumsum()
```

However this does not resolve the dropping below zero criteria you mentioned

Comment: this combined with rhug's sugestion for `clip`:  `df['continuous'] = ((df.col1 != 0 ).cumsum() - (df.col1 == 0 ).cumsum()).clip(0)`

Comment: Thank you. amended

Comment: @DavidErickson this answer can not work if I have 100 starting rows as 0. then next 100 rows with >0 values will still be 0(clipped).

Comment: @SachinVerma in can you update your question with sample data with extra zeros that breaks this?

Comment: @DavidErickson yes, check index 6.

Comment: @DavidErickson `clip` only doesn't solve the problem since it only fixes where the values are negative, but actually positives are also reduced due to `cumsum`.

Answer (score 1):

The key problem here, to me, is to control the out not to go below zero. With that in mind, we can mask the output where it's negative and adjust accordingly:

```
# a little longer data for corner case
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 0,0,0,0,2,3,4]})


s = df.col1.gt(0)
out = s.where(s,-1).cumsum()
df['continuous'] = out - out.where((out<0)&(~s)).ffill().fillna(0)
```

---

Output:

```
    col1 continuous
0      1          1
1      2          2
2      1          3
3      0          2
4      0          1
5      0          0
6      0          0
7      3          1
8      2          2
9      2          3
10     0          2
11     0          1
12     0          0
13     0          0
14     0          0
15     2          1
16     3          2
17     4          3
```